# Unable to convert string type to only date type format in polars python

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to **extract** only `dates` from a `string datetime column` but not able to get proper results. I am not sure but can a single digit format in date create a problem?

data:

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': {0: 2023, 1: 2023, 2: 2023},
 'FL_DATE': {0: '1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM',
  1: '1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM',
  2: '1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM'}})

df = pl.from_pandas(df)
```

Failed attempts:

```
#1
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('FL_DATE').alias('date_only').str.strptime(pl.Date,fmt="%m/%d/%Y").cast(pl.Date)
).select(pl.col('date_only'))

#2
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('FL_DATE').alias('date_only').str.strptime(pl.Date,fmt="%m/%d/%Y").dt.strftime("%Y-%m")
).select(pl.col('date_only'))

#3
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('FL_DATE').alias('date_only').str.strptime(pl.Datetime,fmt="%m/%d/%Y",strict=False).cast(pl.Date)
).select(pl.col('date_only'))

#4
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('FL_DATE').cast(pl.Utf8).str.strptime(pl.Datetime,fmt="%m/%d/%Y",strict=False
                                                      ).cast(pl.Date).alias('date_only')
).select(pl.col('date_only'))
```

failed output:

```
date_only
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you're supplying does not match your data - you're missing the timestamp.

You can also use [`.str.to_date()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_date.html) as of polars `v0.17.10`

```
df.select(
   pl.col("FL_DATE").str.to_date("%m/%d/%Y %r")
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ FL_DATE    │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 │
│ 2023-01-01 │
│ 2023-01-01 │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: @jquirous thanks for letting me know about the new function. Unfortunately its not available in my current version but by changing to `"%m/%d/%Y %r"` worked for me